# tabulator autocomplete that updates another cell

Tags: tabulator

I'm trying to use tabulator as follows:

Pull a set of key->values from a database that contains items similar to:

- 'JohnSmith' -> 'Name is john smith'
- 'AndrewSmith' -. Name is 'andrew smith'

column1
contains an 'autocompete' list that pulls from the keys above. Entering say 'smith' would allow me to select one of the two keys

column2
on selecting the correct option, the cell would be populated with the correct 'Name is...' value

I've tried a number of options, including:

- using a 'cellEdited' callback on the autocomplete cell
- adding a mutator that updates the second cell
- adding an onrendered function to a formatter

I suspect I'm just missing something via javascript, but hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified which Tabulator version you are using but starting with version 5.0 `cellEdited` callback has changed to an event. Therefore, you can now use:

```
table.on("cellEdited", function() {
  //do something
})
```

Here is a working example:

```js
var people = [{
    key: 'John Smith',
    value: 'Name is john smith'
  },
  {
    key: 'Andrew Smith',
    value: 'Name is andrew smith'
  }
]

var tableData = [{
  name: "Oli",
  nameIs: "Name is Oli Bob"
}]

var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
  height: '100%',
  layout: "fitColumns",
  data: tableData,
  columns: [{
      title: "Name",
      field: "name",
      editor: 'autocomplete',
      editorParams: {
        showListOnEmpty: true,
        freetext: true,
        allowEmpty: true,
        searchFunc: (term, values) => {
          const matches = []

          people.forEach(person => {
            const name = person.key
            const nameIs = person.value

            if (name.toLowerCase().startsWith(term.toLowerCase())) {
              matches.push(name)
            }
          })

          return matches
        },
        values: false
      }
    },
    {
      title: "Name Is",
      field: "nameIs"
    }
  ]
})

table.on("cellEdited", (cell) => {
  const name = cell.getValue()
  const row = cell.getRow()
  const nameIs = people.filter(p => p.key == name)[0].value
  row.update({
    "nameIs": nameIs
  })
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>

<div id="example-table"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that Tim. I am using v5. I did try cellEdited, but didn't get the trigger with my autocomplete. I'll try this!